# How to run max 10 threads in one time?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to make 1000 request to a single serwer.

I use threading modul but server  block me.

How to set thread that **run only max 10 thread** in one time (form a list of 1000)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use thread pooling. There's a [thread pooling example](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/#limiting-concurrent-access-to-resources) in Doug Hellman's excellent [threading article](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/).

Answer (score 7):

The [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) provides an undocumented ThreadPool implementation which has an API identical to its multiprocessing pool API:

```
import multiprocessing.pool as mpool

def worker(url):
    # process url

pool = mpool.ThreadPool(10)
for url in tasks:
    pool.apply_async(target=worker, args=(url, ))
```

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)/worker pattern.